# Hiding linux kernel messages from console

Tags: linux, debian, logging, console

I have a machine running a custom build of Linux kernel 3.2.12-rt based on Debian Squeeze.

I'm getting kernel messages printed to the console.  I don't want it to do that.  I know *why* it's doing that:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
8     4     1     3
```

But I don't know how that first value is getting set to 8, and I want whatever is doing it to stop.

I've looked in the kernel config; it has `CONFIG_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL=4` and no built-in command line.

I've looked in the boot command line; it has `quiet`.  I've tried changing it to `quiet loglevel=4`, but this hasn't helped.

`/etc/sysctl.conf` has `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3` (and it's not commented out).

I tried grepping for anything else that might have set printk, but I couldn't find anything useful.  (That may just mean that I didn't look in the right places or for the right things though.)

```
$ grep console /etc/rsyslog.conf
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
         *.notice;*.warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Where else can I look?  (Granted, I could probably rewrite `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` in some boot script, but there has to be a better way.)

Comment: Check your syslog config.

Comment: I looked in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`; there's something at the bottom about logging to `/dev/xconsole` but I don't think that's related.  I couldn't see anything else that could make it log to the console.

Comment: What's the output of `grep console /etc/rsyslog.conf`? Also check in `/etc/rsyslog.d/*` .

Comment: `/etc/rsyslog.d` is empty.  I've added the results of the grep to my question.  I really think the syslog is a red herring -- as I said, the problem is that `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` has the wrong value, not that something **else** is printing log messages to the console.

Comment: do you have the kmsg package installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  `/etc/rc.local` had the following line:

```
dmesg -n 8
```

Removing this returned logging to normal.